# Can Chrome extensions communicate with each other?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension, and want to implement an interface or api so that other extensions made by me in the future can use it. The final effect may be as below:

Extension B calls `extensionA.someMethod(someParameters)` and send some data to extension A, and extension A can return some data to extension B.

Is there some ways to do it, not only using standards method but also some tricks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html has some details on communicating between web pages and extensions. I'm not sure but it might help to have two extensions communicate to each other.

Comment: Specifically, this subsection of that page talks about cross-extension communication: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#external

Comment: Updated messaging URL is https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external