# Chrome extensions communication (content scripts)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I got 2 extensions in Chrome, both only uses content scripts at the moment. Both extensions listen on websocket for messages from the server. Also they both get the same message "same" (obviously a minimal difference) time. After they got the message they both process it and at the end they both have a result which is an int number.

What I would like to do is sending this number from extension A to extension B and from ext. A to ext. B so they both have the other's result.

I've really tried to google a solution for this, but I couldn't find any. Also I would like to avoid sending the results back to the server and then back to the extensions again.

Is there any way (preferably only JS) to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed here: [Can Chrome extensions communicate with each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224881/can-chrome-extensions-communicate-with-each-other)

you can use this api: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(otherExtensionId, {msg: 'hello'},
  function(response) {
    if (response.msg='hi')
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(otherExtensionId, {msg: 'how are you?'});
  });
```

and in the other extension:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.msg=='hello') {
      sendResponse({msg: 'hi'});
    }else ifif (request.msg=='how are you?'){
      doSomething()
    }
});
```

also for another means of communication, you can create an invisible div inside your page, and have both extensions constantly checking if it's contents change.

Comment: Okay, that's how I send the message then, but how do I listen? Could you please write an example for that too? I checked the link you gave me, but it just didn't work for me...

Comment: chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener, its on the second link.

Comment: I tried this code (the sendMessage one), replaced the otherExtensionId  (both), but I'm getting an error:

Error in event handler for (unknown): Cannot set property 'msg' of undefined
Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot set property 'msg' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://nfcdihpggcaeipibmkpeafpobgomeapl/ext.js:17:33
    at disconnectListener (extensions::messaging:335:9)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:397:22)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) ...

Comment: are you running this in the background page?

Comment: Nope, content script as I said in the title. Should it be in the background page?

Comment: yup. you cant run messaging inside content scripts, only background pages

Comment: Just a last question, if you don't mind. Since the messaging will be in the background js, how can I pass the message I got to the content script?

Comment: ah, do some research!

Comment: @JohnSmith When TAA said "you can't run messaging in content scripts", it's not entirely true. But you need to use a different function/listener, in particular look into `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`.